# Using require with webpack in my Chrome Extensions blocks my async calls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, requirejs, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a Chrome Extension that does *STT* to Google Documents. It works fine, I managed to add some features to it, but now I want to add an option to select some text from the document. For this I am using a GET request, something like this:

```
const getCurrentParagraph = async (token, ID) => {
const postLinkDocs = `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${ID}`;
    try {
        await fetch(postLinkDocs, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => { gets my data corectly });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Batch update error:', error);
        formatingMode = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tested it also with *Postman* and it works, I am getting the correct data from Docs. With this data, I want that the user can style it by saying words like "bold", "italic" etc. To know exactly what the user said ( for example maybe it says "bol", not "bold" ) I am using a function that does Levenshtein Distance from a package here: https://github.com/gustf/js-levenshtein importing it as:

```
const levenshtein = require('js-levenshtein');
```

So the order of my program is: get data from docs, get user style, and use this style. For the first time, it works just fine, I am getting the correct style and is applying correctly. But calling this program again blocks the data collection ( `await getCurrentParagraph(myToken, myDocumentID;` ). **Not** using require to get *levenshtein* function (getting it as a global function ) works without a problem, I can constantly update my Docs.

Note: My Extension is bundled with WebPack ( this is why I can use require in the first place ) and I am using Manifest V3

Comment: do you see any error messages?

Comment: Nope, I don't get any error messages.